# Plotting simulating bouncing

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I need help with a challenge problem.

Assume the ball is dropped on Venus under constant acceleration g=8.87ms2 from the limit of its atmosphere, a height of 250km. Model the ball's motion for one hour and 15 minutes (include second 00 and second 4,500 in your data points). After the initial state, simulate 5,000 updates to the state (for a total of 5,001 points.) Your simulation should use float64 numpy arrays for time (t) and height (y). Time should be represented in seconds and height should be represented in meters.

To simulate bouncing, we'll make some simplifying assumptions (since collision detection can be complicated). If the ball's height is ever less than or equal to 0, we will assume that the ball hit the ground before the time step we are simulating and already started bouncing. You should:

1. instantly set its height to 0
2. update its velocity to 90% (0.9) of its velocity from the previous time slice of the simulation
3. change the direction of travel (up instead of down)—in this case, please use the now-current velocity, i.e., vc[ i ] = -0.9 * vc[ i ]

Count the number of times the ball bounces in an integer variable named bounces.

**Your submission should include arrays t and y of the proper dimensions and values, and an int named bounces.**

Here is my code so far. It says my y values are incorrect.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g=-8.87
t=np.linspace(0,4500,5001,dtype=np.float64)
v=np.zeros(5001)
y=np.zeros(5001)
bounces=0
y[0]=250000
for i in range(1,5001):
if y[i-1]+0.9*v[i-1]>0:
    v[i]=v[i-1]+g*(0.9)
    y[i]=y[i-1]+0.9*v[i-1]
if y[i-1]+0.9*v[i-1]<=0:
    v[i]=-0.9*v[i]
    y[i]=0
bounces+=1
```

Comment: Can't see the mistake in the y-values. But the bounces +=1 should be indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with the indentation, the for loop isn't indented and the bounces iterator is in the wrong place. So I fixed that.

Also, on the 3rd line from the bottom you set `v[i] = -0.9*v[i]`, which is the current timestep, when you want the previous timestep. So that should be `v[i]=-0.9*v[i-1]`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g=-8.87
t=np.linspace(0,4500,5001,dtype=np.float64)
v=np.zeros(5001)
y=np.zeros(5001)
bounces=0
y[0]=250000
for i in range(1,5001):
  if y[i-1]+0.9*v[i-1]>0:
    v[i]=v[i-1]+g*(0.9)
    y[i]=y[i-1]+0.9*v[i-1]
  if y[i-1]+0.9*v[i-1]<=0:
    v[i]=-0.9*v[i-1]
    y[i]=0
    bounces+=1
```

You can see an example here https://repl.it/NCWu

Answer (score 0):

Big s/o to chasmani for their help on this question, however the internal loop is incorrect. Because it shouldn't be two if statements in the for loop, rather one. This is because these calculations should occur in each and every interval. Here's the answer :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g=-8.87
t=np.linspace(0,4500,5001,dtype=np.float64)
v=np.zeros(5001)
y=np.zeros(5001)
bounces=0
y[0]=250000
for i in range(1,5001):
    v[i]=v[i-1]+g*(0.9)
    y[i]=y[i-1]+0.9*v[i-1]
    if y[i]<=0:
        v[i]=-0.9*v[i]
        y[i]=0
        bounces+=1
```

Hope this helped.